# Azure kubernetes - writing logs on the console for production application?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

Currently my azure log analytics is configured to pull the logs from the console and the production application on aks cluster would directly log on the console.

Being heavy used application, would writing the logs on the console cause any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** it is But very minimal. The result or impact vary depending on the kind of hardware you are running on and the load on the host. Unless your application does 99% Console.WriteLine() and barely anything else, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: Would you recommend this approach over sidecar pattern (fluentd) for production application?

Comment: made me laugh, negligible as long as you dont starve the os disk and turn your aks cluster into a wreck.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can you elaborate more?. using graphana or fluentd is much better approach according to my knowledge